# Kubernetes equivalent of env-file in Docker

Tags: configuration, docker, environment-variables, configuration-files, kubernetes

**Background:**

Currently we're using Docker and Docker Compose for our services. We have externalized the configuration for different environments into files that define environment variables read by the application. For example a `prod.env` file:

```
ENV_VAR_ONE=Something Prod
ENV_VAR_TWO=Something else Prod
```

and a `test.env` file:

```
ENV_VAR_ONE=Something Test
ENV_VAR_TWO=Something else Test
```

Thus we can simply use the `prod.env` or `test.env` file when starting the container:

```
docker run --env-file prod.env <image>
```

Our application then picks up its configuration based on the environment variables defined in `prod.env`.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to provide environment variables from a file in Kubernetes (for example when defining a pod) instead of hardcoding them like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  labels: 
    context: docker-k8s-lab
    name: mysql-pod
  name: mysql-pod
spec: 
  containers: 
    - 
      env: 
        - 
          name: MYSQL_USER
          value: mysql
        - 
          name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          value: mysql
        - 
          name: MYSQL_DATABASE
          value: sample
        - 
          name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: supersecret
      image: "mysql:latest"
      name: mysql
      ports: 
        - 
          containerPort: 3306
```

2. If this is not possible, what is the suggested approach?

Comment: I am also looking for something like this. I don't want to create a `Secret` or `ConfigMap` resource because this is just temporary and use for testing. I have limited permissions in the k8s cluster. I maybe be able to create a `Secret` resource but I won't be able to delete them once it is already created.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can populate a container's environment variables through the use of [Secrets](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/) or [ConfigMaps](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/configmap/). Use Secrets when the data you are working with is sensitive (e.g. passwords), and ConfigMaps when it is not.

In your Pod definition specify that the container should pull values from a Secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: 
  labels: 
    context: docker-k8s-lab
    name: mysql-pod
  name: mysql-pod
spec: 
  containers:
  - image: "mysql:latest"
    name: mysql
    ports: 
    - containerPort: 3306
    envFrom:
      - secretRef:
         name: mysql-secret
```

Note that this syntax is only available in Kubernetes 1.6 or later. On an earlier version of Kubernetes you will have to specify each value manually, e.g.:

```
env: 
- name: MYSQL_USER
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: mysql-secret
      key: MYSQL_USER
```

**(Note that `env` take an array as value)**

And repeating for every value.

Whichever approach you use, you can now define two different Secrets, one for production and one for dev.

dev-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_USER: bXlzcWwK
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: bXlzcWwK
  MYSQL_DATABASE: c2FtcGxlCg==
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: c3VwZXJzZWNyZXQK
```

prod-secret.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  MYSQL_USER: am9obgo=
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: c2VjdXJlCg==
  MYSQL_DATABASE: cHJvZC1kYgo=
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: cm9vdHkK
```

And deploy the correct secret to the correct Kubernetes cluster:

```
kubectl config use-context dev
kubectl create -f dev-secret.yaml

kubectl config use-context prod
kubectl create -f prod-secret.yaml
```

Now whenever a Pod starts it will populate its environment variables from the values specified in the Secret.

Comment: This is my current approach, however I have 3 different pods using the same list of secrets exposed as EnvVars. Is it possible to define them once and expose them to the 3 pods?

Comment: that would be so great... seems like allot of boilerplate to get the env vars into containers. @PixelElephant

Comment: @jävi Do you mean replication controllers? Regardless, there's nothing binding a secret/config map to a single pod/RC/Deployment. It's just defined in the manifest as above, and can be mounted to as many things as you would like.

Comment: @aronchick I believe they are looking for this feature: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/26299 which looks like it will be landing soon. I'll update the answer once the feature is in a released version of Kubernetes.

Comment: I think it's important to mention that the values MUST be base64 encoded, in the definition of the Secret. I just tried this with my learning cluster and I get error unless the values are all base64 encoded

Comment: Correct syntax is in the answer below, please fix in your answer, otherwise it generates error. You need a dash before secretRef and two spaces before name.

Comment: @Pixel Elephant, how would i use env for docker image so i don't have to update deployment.yaml every time i need to increment a version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343649/kubernetes-warning-for-clashes-while-using-env-variable-in-docker-why  my question also is related to env variable . Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 75):

**A new update for Kubernetes(v1.6)** allows what you asked for(years ago).

You can now use the `envFrom` like this in your yaml file:

```
  containers:
  - name: django
    image: image/name
    envFrom:
      - secretRef:
         name: prod-secrets
```

Where development-secrets is your secret, you can create it by:

```
kubectl create secret generic prod-secrets --from-env-file=prod/env.txt`
```

Where the txt file content is a key-value:

```
DB_USER=username_here
DB_PASSWORD=password_here
```

The docs are still lakes of examples, I had to search really hard on those places:

- [Secrets docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/), search for `--from-file` - shows that this option is available.
- [The equivalent `ConfigMap` docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files) shows an example on how to use it.

**Note:** there's a difference between `--from-file` and `--from-env-file` when creating secret as described in the comments below.

Comment: Can you share Kubernetes documentation on this?

Comment: @ArtemDolobanko Edited, keep in mind this is still new and lakes of docs, you can find many discussions on Github's issues tracker if you want more details.

Comment: @Or Duan how would i pass a version number to docker image using env

Comment: what if we have to mount that text file to some location and the app will create the env automatically from there

Comment: Should this be `--from-env-file`? Using `--from-file` results in one key (named after the input file) with the content of the file. Using `--from-env-file` expands the keys inside the file into the secret. See [this Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#secret-from-env-file) for more.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72343649/kubernetes-warning-for-clashes-while-using-env-variable-in-docker-why … my question also is related to env variable . Please help me to sort this out

Answer (score 13):

When defining a pod for Kubernetes using a YAML file, there's no direct way to specify a different file containing environment variables for a container. The Kubernetes project says they will improve this area in the future (see [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables)).

In the meantime, I suggest using a provisioning tool and making the pod YAML a template. For example, using Ansible your pod YAML file would look like:

file `my-pod.yaml.template`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  ...
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: {{ mysql_root_pasword }}
    ...
```

Then your Ansible playbook can specify the variable `mysql_root_password` somewhere convenient, and substitute it when creating the resource, for example:

file `my-playbook.yaml`:

```
- hosts: my_hosts
  vars_files: 
  - my-env-vars-{{ deploy_to }}.yaml
  tasks:
  - name: create pod YAML from template
    template: src=my-pod.yaml.template dst=my-pod.yaml
  - name: create pod in Kubernetes
    command: kubectl create -f my-pod.yaml
```

file `my-env-vars-prod.yaml`:

```
mysql_root_password: supersecret
```

file `my-env-vars-test.yaml`:

```
mysql_root_password: notsosecret
```

Now you create the pod resource by running, for example:

```
ansible-playbook -e deploy=test my-playbook.yaml
```

Comment: Ideally you should be able to define a Secret (or the eventual config objects we will have) and have that injected as env vars.  Unfortunately that work is not done yet, so I am voting for this.

Comment: If you're using ansible, we have a common role to deploy on kubernetes: https://github.com/ansibl8s/k8s-common.   Then it's very easy to prepare new applications, see exemples how to use it in other repo: https://github.com/ansibl8s

Comment: I am hoping that we will do secrets in env vars for 1.2

Comment: Note that there is a proposal for templates: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/proposals/templates.md

Comment: what should I do if i want to use `kubectl-run` to pass 20 env variables??? why then don't do 12factor easier??

Comment: Can this work.  At least in my case it does not work.  Please see my issue https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/38858 . Will you please have a look to see if I am wrong at some part. Thank you!

Comment: This is no longer correct. The higher voted answer (below) is the correct answer.

Comment: how would i use env for docker image so i don't have to update deployment.yaml every time i need to increment a version

Answer (score 11):

This works for me:

file `env-secret.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: env-secret
type: Opaque
stringData:
  .env: |-
    APP_NAME=Laravel
    APP_ENV=local
```

and into the `deployment.yaml` or `pod.yaml`

`````
spec:
  ...
        volumeMounts:
        - name: foo
          mountPath: "/var/www/html/.env"
          subPath: .env
      volumes:
      - name: foo
        secret:
          secretName: env-secret
````
`````

Comment: how would i use env for docker image so i don't have to update deployment.yaml every time i need to increment a version

Comment: Referencing '/var/www/html/.env' is creating a `.env` folder instead of the filename for me.

Answer (score 6):

I smashed my head aupon tyhis for 2 hours now. I found in the docs a very simple solution to minimize my (and hopefully your) pain.

- Keep `env.prod`, `env.dev` as you have them.
- Use a oneliner script to import those into yaml:

  `kubectl create configmap my-dev-config --from-env-file=env.dev`

  `kubectl create configmap my-prod-config --from-env-file=env.prod`

You can see the result (for instant gratification):

```
# You can also save this to disk
kubectl get configmap my-dev-config -o yaml
```

As a rubyist, I personally find this solution the DRYest as you have a single point to maintain (the ENV bash file, which is compatible with Python/Ruby libraries, ..) and then you YAMLize it in a single execution.

Note that you need to keep your ENV file clean (I have a lot of comments which prevented this to work so had to prepend a `cat config.original | egrep -v "^#" | tee config.cleaned`) but this doen't change the complexity substantially.

It's all documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but let me describe my answer for future beginner.

You can use kustomize configMapGenerator.

```
configMapGenerator:
  - name: example
    env: dev.env
```

and refer this configMap/example in pod definition

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it has a lot of viewers so I add my answer.
The best way to separate the configuration from K8s implementation is using Helm. Each Helm package can have a `values.yaml` file and we can easily use those values in the Helm chart. If we have a multi-component topology we can create an umbrella Helm package and the parent values package also can overwrite the children values files.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference K8S values by specifying them in your container as environment variables.

let your deployment be mongo.yml as follows:

```
--
kind: Deployment
   --
      --
      containers:
        --
        env:
        - name: DB_URL
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongo-config
              key: mongo-url
        - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-secret
              key: mongo-password
```

Where mongo-secret is used for senective data, e.g.: passwords or certificates

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-user: bW9uZ291c2Vy
  mongo-password: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==
```

and mongo-config is used for non-sensitive data

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongo-config
data:
  mongo-url: mongo-service
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this steps:

This command will put your file `prod.env` in the secrets.

```
kubectl create secret generic env-prod --from-file=prod.env=prod.env
```

Then, you could reference this file in your deployment.yaml like

```html
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-identity
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: api-identity
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: api-identity
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: api-identity
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: docker-registry-credential
      containers:
        - name: api-identity
          image: "api-identity:test"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8005
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - name: env-file-vol
            mountPath: "/var/www/html/.env"
            subPath: .env
      volumes:
      - name: env-file-vol
        secret:
          secretName: env-prod
```